# Seg Fault Callback Issues in a C++ Class Extended in Python

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, callback, virtual

I'm wrapping an abstract C++ class with SWIG for Python, and am running into seg fault issues.  Here is a simplified version of the code I'm dealing with.  ("Changes" is an enum.)

**Foo.h**

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual ~Foo() {};

    virtual void OnStateChange(Changes change) = 0;
};
```

Then in Python.

**test.py**

```py
class MyFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyFoo).__init__(self)

    def OnStateChange(self, change):
        print("the state has changed to", change)
```

I then pass an instance of MyFoo to the C++ lib (via a SWIG-wrapped function), and the C++ code attempts to call OnStateChange.  The first time it is called I see the output from the print statement, the second time the program crashes with a seg fault.

I have read the SWIG documentation here http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_directors on implementing what I am trying to do and I have directors enabled.  I know this may not be enough information to go on, but I've been searching high and low for the past several days and haven't found anything satisfactory.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post enough code so that someone looking at this could actually reproduce the specific error just by compiling + copy/paste? (it would be preferable if you could try to strip out everything that isn't necessary for producing the error--heck, you might even find the problem in the process). Doing this would make it much easier to find an answer.  Here's some guidance on how to make an [SSCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  In trying to replicate the issue on a small scale I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

After trying to create a small example I discovered the issue.  I had forgotten that the C++ code was running it's own thread, and trying to call into the Python thread.  All that had to be done to solve the problem was add the -threads option to the swig command.